# How do I find the tangent to a parameterized curve at a point $t$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, parametric

So I have a question that goes like this:

> The parametric equations of a curve are
> $$x = \frac{1}{\cos^3t}, y = \tan^3t$$
> where $0 \le t \lt \frac{1}{2}\pi$.
>
> (i) Show that $\frac{dy}{dx} = \sin t $
>
> (ii) Hence show that the equation of the tangent to the curve at the point with parameter t is $y = x\sin t - \tan t$.

(i) is easy enough, but I have no idea where to even start with (ii), considering I don't know what the value of $t$ at this point is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you think (i) is easy enough, you should know what does the result in (i) means. It actually tells you the **slope** in (ii), that is to say, the slope of the tangent line to the curve is actually $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, which equals to $\sin t$. Then for a line going through the point $(x(t),y(t))$ with slope $\sin t$, we can write the line equation as
$$
\frac{y-y(t)}{x-x(t)}=\sin t
$$
Thus
$$
y-\tan ^3t=\sin t\left( x-\frac{1}{\cos ^3t} \right) 
\\
y=x\sin t+\tan ^3t-\frac{\sin t}{\cos ^3t} = x \sin t-\tan t
$$

As desired.

Notice that we are calculating for a general $t$, so we don't need to know what the value of $t$. We calculate for general points $(x(t),y(t))$.

Comment: Ah ok, I just never had to solve for a general $t$ before. Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: My pleasure.  :D

Answer (score 3):

Use $\frac{y-y(t)}{x-x(t)}=\frac{dy}{dx}\Big|_t$. You don't need to know the value of $t$, we can calculate the tangent for a general $t$.